# How can I pass the scope into a directive?

Tags: angularjs

I created the following directive:

```
app.directive('myActivity', function() {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            template: "<div class='activity-mask' data-ng-show='loading!=0'>" +
                       "<span>Loading... {{ loading }}</span>" + 
                       "</div>" +
                       "<div class='activity-mask' data-ng-show='fetching!=0'>" +
                       "<span>Fetching... {{ fetching }}</span>" +
                       "</div>"
        };
});
```

The directive seems not to notice the $scope. How can I pass in the scope so that I can see the values of $scope.fetching and $scope.loading?

Comment: Since your directive is not creating isolated scope, it can access parent scope elements without any issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an isolate scope with `@` since you wish to pass read-only values to the directive:

```
app.directive('myActivity', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope:{
            loading:"@",
            fetching:"@"
        },
        template: '<div>...</div>'
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div my-activity loading="{{loading}}" fetching="{{fetching}}"></div>
```

This approach is safe and does not pollute the parent scope: <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EMPe3/)**</kbd>

However if you want the directive to share the parent's scope, here's a demo fiddle: <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D5tYc/)**</kbd>

Another safe way is to create a bi-dimensional binding:

```
app.directive('myActivity', function() {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            scope:{
                loading : "=",
                fetching : "=",
            },
            template: '<div>...</div>'
        };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div my-activity loading="loading" fetching="fetching"...
```

Comment: Thanks but I just need a one way binding. Would that be simpler?  The numbers are set outside of the directive and just read-only inside the directive. Can I pass the whole $scope to the directive?